# ListViewItem text is not shown fully on the listview control of C# windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

ListViewItem text is not shown fully on the listview control of C# windows forms.

Is there any limit to show text of listview item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `ListView` `View` property to `List` may solve your problem.

Comment: Will it not work for Details???... this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean some of the text shown and some of it isn't shown? Like this => "Sample te..."

If it is, make sure GridLines set to "true", then change width of the column.

Comment: The text of list view item contains more than 256 characters but Only 256 characters of text is shown. why?